# What populations have been denied the ability to leave a territory, so that its goverment could kill them?

Tags: genocide

There are well known examples such as Jewish populations in WW2, and some of the ethnic minorities in Khmer Rouge Cambodia, who although considered an enemy population, were prevented from leaving a territory, because the government of that region had decided to kill them at a later time, or to one way or another dispose of the population in ways that were incompatible with permitting them to leave.

What are the other cases in recent history where this happened?  In Rwanda the Tutsis were barred from leaving once the massacre began, but things proceeded very quickly and I do not know whether there was some prior restriction on travel to set the stage for the atrocities.

Answer (score 2):

There are the tribes of Sudan especially around the Darfur province and the mountains south of the capital, Khartoum; which has been going on for a while now. The muslim government under Al Bashir is targeting many local ethnic groups throughout the country and especially Christians. They are pretty much animals to them. They have no right to leave, to acquire provisions or weaponry to fight back. It was actually possible to see a large excavation that was made to dispose of a mass of bodies on a satellite image.